# Changing Queries Table Adapter Database Connection

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, xsd, dataset

I’m trying to update the connection string for each of the Queries in a QueriesTableAdapter I have created inside a DataSet (XSD file). I have made method which tries to do this via reflection (I have a similar method working with table adapters) however it can’t seem to access the Queries. Here is the method I have made:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Changes the database all the queries in a queries table adapter connect to
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="IQA">The type of the queries table adapter</typeparam>
        /// <param name="InstanceQueriesAdapter">The instance of the queries table adapter</param>
        /// <param name="sqlDatabaseName">The name of the database the queries table adapter queries should connect to</param>
        public static void GetInstanceQueriesAdapter<IQA>(ref IQA InstanceQueriesAdapter, string sqlDatabaseName)
        {
            try
            {
                PropertyInfo qAdapterCommandCollection = InstanceQueriesAdapter.GetType().GetProperty("CommandCollection");

                if (qAdapterCommandCollection != null)
                {
                    SqlCommand[] qaCC = (SqlCommand[])qAdapterCommandCollection.GetValue(InstanceQueriesAdapter, null);

                    foreach (SqlCommand singleCommand in qaCC)
                    {
                        SqlConnection newSQLConnection = singleCommand.Connection;

                        SqlConnectionStringBuilder csBulider = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(newSQLConnection.ConnectionString);

                        csBulider.InitialCatalog = sqlDatabaseName;

                        newSQLConnection.ConnectionString = csBulider.ConnectionString;

                        singleCommand.Connection = newSQLConnection;
                    }

                    qAdapterCommandCollection.SetValue(InstanceQueriesAdapter, qaCC, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Could not find command collection.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception _exception)
            {
                throw new Exception(_exception.ToString());
            }
        }
```

It is failing as the GetProperty method is returning null. However you can see here the property does exist:

[image: 1]

Here is an output from the Immediate Window:

```
? InstanceQueriesAdapter.GetType().GetProperties()
{System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[2]}
    [0]: {System.ComponentModel.ISite Site}
    [1]: {System.ComponentModel.IContainer Container}
? InstanceQueriesAdapter.GetType().GetMethods()
{System.Reflection.MethodInfo[14]}
    [0]: {System.Object ImportProcess(System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Nullable`1[System.Guid], System.String ByRef)}
    [1]: {Void add_Disposed(System.EventHandler)}
    [2]: {Void remove_Disposed(System.EventHandler)}
    [3]: {System.ComponentModel.ISite get_Site()}
    [4]: {Void set_Site(System.ComponentModel.ISite)}
    [5]: {Void Dispose()}
    [6]: {System.ComponentModel.IContainer get_Container()}
    [7]: {System.String ToString()}
    [8]: {System.Object GetLifetimeService()}
    [9]: {System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()}
    [10]: {System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(System.Type)}
    [11]: {Boolean Equals(System.Object)}
    [12]: {Int32 GetHashCode()}
    [13]: {System.Type GetType()}
```

Does anyone know of a way to get to this "CommandCollection" so I can dynamically change the connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code to change the database. It is also worth noting that all parts of the connection can be changed here such as the timeout etc..

```
/// <summary>
/// Changes the database all the queries in a queries table adapter connect to
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="IQA">The type of the queries table adapter</typeparam>
/// <param name="InstanceQueriesAdapter">The instance of the queries table adapter</param>
/// <param name="sqlDatabaseName">The name of the database the queries table adapter queries should connect to</param>
public static void GetInstanceQueriesAdapter<IQA>(ref IQA InstanceQueriesAdapter, string sqlDatabaseName)
{
    try
    {
        FieldInfo qAdapterCommandCollection = InstanceQueriesAdapter.GetType().GetField("_commandCollection", BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        MethodInfo initCC = InstanceQueriesAdapter.GetType().GetMethod("InitCommandCollection", BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        if (qAdapterCommandCollection != null && initCC != null)
        {
            initCC.Invoke(InstanceQueriesAdapter, null);

            IDbCommand[] qaCC = (IDbCommand[])qAdapterCommandCollection.GetValue(InstanceQueriesAdapter);

            foreach (SqlCommand singleCommand in qaCC)
            {
                SqlConnection newSQLConnection = singleCommand.Connection;

                SqlConnectionStringBuilder csBulider = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(newSQLConnection.ConnectionString);

                csBulider.InitialCatalog = sqlDatabaseName;

                newSQLConnection.ConnectionString = csBulider.ConnectionString;

                singleCommand.Connection = newSQLConnection;
            }

            qAdapterCommandCollection.SetValue(InstanceQueriesAdapter, qaCC);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not find command collection.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception _exception)
    {
        throw new Exception(_exception.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the CommandCollection property is protected; try this instead:

```
GetProperty( "CommandCollection", BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic )
```

Comment: Thanks, that has allowed me to get the CommandCollections. However I am now getting a error when I try and set the property saying "Property set method not found." I tried putting in some BindingFlags into the SetProperty method but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: It may very well be that the property doesn't have a setter. In which case, you should find a way to deal with the collection by **add/clear/remove** methods of to the collection. Also, in theory, since there's a field behind the property, you could access the field instead. Personally, I would never replace a collection for which there's no setter, let alone this whole funky stuff.... if the field is protected, and the class is not final, I would explore instead if there's a posibility to use a subtype, which would give you "legal" access to the protected property, etc.

Comment: Using the field actually worked :). I have edited my question with my working code.